# Can´t get Session info from one php paganother

Tags: php, html, xml, session, authentication

I´ve been looking for some answers here but nothing worked for me so far. I am learning HTML and while doing a simple login I have encountered some problems. I am using XML as a "database" and php to get the info. This is how my php code looks:

```
<?php
$error = false;
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (file_exists('users/'.$username.'.xml')){
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('users/'.$username.'.xml',0,true);
        if($password == $xml->password){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $direccion = $xml->direccion;
            $_SESSION['direccion'] = $direccion;
            header('Location: carta.php');
            die;
        }
    }
    $error = true;
}
?>
```

I know that I am able to search through XML files and correctly finds the user because it redirects me to carta.php and it gives an error If its not founded, but in the other php page I cannot get info from:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> // This code is inside html code
```

The error I am getting is : Notice: Undefined index: username in C:....

Taking into account I already initialize the session with

```
<?php session_start();?>
```

in the beginning, why can´t I get info from the echo?

Thanks in advance,

Luka.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP Session works right of the bat as soon as you have initialised it.
PHP can handle session in two normal ways as a cookie session or locally stored session on the backend server. The last one is default. PHP can also use Memcache/Redis for Sessions.

Please make sure your PHP sessions are working first. You would do that by a simple test. Also remember that session_start() needs to be included in all files that you expect to use the session environment in!

```
<?PHP
 session_start();
 $_SESSION["mytest"] = time();
?>
```

and then try to echo that Unix timestamp out from another file.

```
<?PHP
 session_start();
 echo "SESSION var(mytest): ".$_SESSION["mytest"]."\n";
?>
```

This should produce as expected that the SESSION variable "mytest" is set in one file and can be retrieved from another file. Don't forget to start that session in each file. This is what "retrieves" the SESSION environment.

If that works for you, then you can move on to your $_SESSION["username"] code and you know that there is something wrong with your code and not the session environment.

Also session_start() needs to be initialised as some of the first thing, it's not generally good practice to initialise it inside your condition.

Comment: Session seems to be working just fine as the var(mytest) is correctly displayed. I have realized that the problem is inside the IF statement. As long as I assign something to  $_SESSION["username"] before the If statement I can access to it later on. But I have to assign it inside it :(